# How do I make a Collection of Generically Typed Structs in Rust?

Tags: list, generics, collections, rust

I am creating a text based monopoly game in Rust as a personal project. My current setup is to have the various kinds of spaces as their own structs (for example, `Property`)

```
use space::Event;

pub struct Property {
    message: String,
}

impl Property {
    pub fn new() -> Property {
        let message = String::from("Hello World!");
        Property { message: message }
    }
}

impl Event for Property {
    fn event(&self) {
        print!("{}", &self.message);
    }
}
```

and a generic `Space` struct that contains an instance of one of the types of spaces (`Space<Property>` or `Space<Chance>` for example).

```
pub trait Event {
    fn event(&self);
}

pub struct Space<T> {
    item: T,
}

impl<T: Event> Space<T> {
    pub fn new(item: T) -> Space<T> {
        Space { item: item }
    }

    pub fn event(&self) {
        &self.item.event();
    }
}
```

Each type of space implements a trait that requires it to have an "event" method, which the generic Space struct can call. Then I have a `Game` struct that will contain some sort of collection of spaces (among other things).

```
pub struct Game {
    spaces: Vec<Space>, // Does not work
}
```

Unfortunately I'm running into an issue creating this collection. No matter which one I try it tells me I have to specify a type argument for Space. How can I make a collection of structs that are generically typed? It would be preferable if I can pull up a particular space by its index, as that will make it easier when I start to implement certain `Chance` cards that move you to particular spaces later down the line. Apologies if I'm missing something obvious, I'm new-ish to Rust so I don't always necessarily know what to look for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rust compiler needs to know how big each element in your Vec will be to decide how to lay out memory (each element must take up the same amount of space). Your `Space` struct has a type parameter `T` so it's not clear how much space a `Space` will take unless you provide the type parameter too. E.g. `Vec<Space<i32>>` would work.

If you want a `Vec` of differently sized objects, a common approach is to use a vector of [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html). In your example you could have a `Vec<Box<Event>>`, a vector of objects that implement the `Event` trait, each element of the vec here is a Box (smart pointer) to a heap-allocated type that implements `Event`.

```
pub trait Event {
    fn event(&self);
}

pub struct Property {
    message: String,
}

impl Property {
    pub fn new(message: String) -> Property {
        Property { message }
    }
}

impl Event for Property {
    fn event(&self) {
        println!("{}", &self.message);
    }
}

pub struct Utility {
    message: String,
}

impl Utility {
    pub fn new(message: String) -> Utility {
        Utility { message }
    }
}

impl Event for Utility {
    fn event(&self) {
        println!("{}", &self.message);
    }
}

pub struct Game {
    pub spaces: Vec<Box<Event>>,
}

fn main () {
    let game = Game{ 
        spaces: vec![
            Box::new(Utility::new(String::from("Water works"))),
            Box::new(Property::new(String::from("Fleet Street"))),
            Box::new(Utility::new(String::from("Electric company"))),
            Box::new(Property::new(String::from("Bond Street"))),
        ] 
    };

    for space in game.spaces {
        space.event();
    }
}

// Water works
// Fleet Street
// Electric company
// Bond Street
```

Comment: Note: in Rust 2018, we prefer to prefix traits that are used as trait objects with the `dyn` keyword. So `Vec<Box<dyn Event>>` would be more idiomatic :)

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't known about smart pointers yet, but your explanation was very helpful!